# Updating Database Field with AJAX Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update my stock level by subtracting the cart item quantity from  the product quantity in the database when a user completes an order using the POST method. Everytime I run the method the success function occurs but the field doesnt update doesnt update.

Could anyone tell me why?

My Controller:

```
public function index ()
{
    $products = Product::all();


    return view('products', compact('products'));
}


public function cart()

{
    return view('cart');
}

public function addToCart($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    if(!$product) {

        abort(404);

    }

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // if cart is empty then this will be the first product
    if(!$cart) {

        $cart = [
                $id => [
                    "name" => $product->name,
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "price" => $product->unit_price
                ]
        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }

    // if cart isnt empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
    if(isset($cart[$id])) {

        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

    }

    // if item doesnt exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
    $cart[$id] = [
        "name" => $product->name,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "price" => $product->unit_price
    ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    if($request->id and $request->quantity)
    {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        $cart[$request->id]["quantity"] = $request->quantity;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        session()->flash('success', 'Cart updated successfully');
    }
}

public function remove(Request $request)
{
    if($request->id) {

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        if(isset($cart[$request->id])) {

            unset($cart[$request->id]);

            session()->put('cart', $cart);
        }

        session()->flash('success', 'Product removed successfully');
    }
}

public function stock (Request $request)
{
    if($request->id and $request->quantity)
    {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        $cart[$request->id]['quantity'] = $request->quantity;

        $products = Product::all();

        $stock = $products->unit_stock;

        $quantity = $stock - $cart;

        return $quantity;
    }
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('stock', 'ProductController@stock');
```

My view cart.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout')



@section('content')

<table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">Product</th>
        <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
        <th style="width:8%">Quantity</th>
        <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
        <th style="width:10%"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php $total = 0 ?>

    @if(session('cart'))
        @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)

            <?php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ?>

            <tr>
                <td data-th="Product">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h4 class="nomargin">{{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td data-th="Price">${{ $details['price'] }}</td>
                <td data-th="Quantity">
                    <input type="number" value="{{ $details['quantity'] }}" class="form-control quantity" />
                </td>
                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">${{ $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] }}</td>
                <td class="actions" data-th="">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm update-cart" data-id="{{ $id }}"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart" data-id="{{ $id }}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr class="visible-xs">
        <td class="text-center"><strong>Total {{ $total }}</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ url('/products') }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a></td>
        <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total ${{ $total }}</strong></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="btn col-md-12">
           <a href="{{ url('/cart') }}" id="order-complete">Test</a>
       </div>

    </div>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#order-complete").click(function (e){
       e.preventDefault();

        var ele = $(this);

        $.ajax({
           url: '{{ url('stock') }}',
           method: "post",
           data: {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
           success: function () {

            window.location.reload();
           }
        });
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

Comment: did you check if the $cart contain the intended data ?

Comment: This seems confusing.
How could $products->unit_stock work as long as $product returns a collection.

Comment: 1) You're never saving it in the database. 2) I'm surprised you're not getting an error, since `$products` is a collection of objects and not a single product.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of potential issues that might be causing this. Firstly, it looks like you're trying to set stock against all of the products in your database in one go by loading a collection containing them all, rather than looping/loading the ones contained in the order ($request). You do this here;

```
$products = Product::all();
```

Then you try to change the stock for *all products in the collection* here;

```
$stock = $products->unit_stock;

$quantity = $stock - $cart;
```

I imagine you should have a collection of products in your `$cart` variable that you should loop over and load to manipulate. Some pseudo code to illustrate my point;

```
foreach($product in $cart){
  $loadedProduct        = Product::find($product);
  $loadedProduct->stock = $loadedProduct->stock - $product["quantity"];
  $loadedProduct->save(); 
}
```

You also aren't saving any products in the code you provided. There's an example of this in the pseudo code above.

Comment: Hi Lewis, thanks for this i understand it better! just a couple things, in the foreach statement, "in" isnt recognised as syntax, would "as" be suitable? When i changed it to this the page worked, however when I get a 500 error now when the Ajax method starts

Comment: Hey. Yes, "as" is correct here, sorry had just been writing similar code in JS :) The code above is pseudo only. Have you changed it to match your own?

Comment: What would I need to change? I have changed just "stock" to "unit_stock" as that is the field in the database, would that be everything?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, as I can't see your cart object. I am only guessing from what you posted but it looks like your cart object is just an array of products with the keys set as product ids? If that's the case, in the foreach I posted, drop the products key. Inside, use just `Product::find($product)` to load the product. I'm on mobile right now so will help later if I can and if these changes don't work.

Comment: Great thanks! I have updated my question so you see my full controller

Comment: Hey, have a look at my edited answer. This should get it.

Comment: Still getting a 500 error on the console log, I have no idea why im getting this because I have an csrf token, so frustrating!

Comment: I'm not sure how to move this to chat on mobile - but I believe the 500 essentially will boil down to variable names / array keys used in the controller. If you've copied my code verbatim, there's a good chance I've named something incorrectly. If it were the csrf token, you'd have a different error.

Comment: @Jeff check your network tab for a response from the ajax request. Press 'F12'.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot a few mistakes from your code.

1. Lets focus on the function that the ajax request calls.

This line here tells me that there is a data `id` and `quantity` being sent.

```
if($request->id and $request->quantity)
```

From the look of your Route, it is in the body. But in the ajax function, you're didn't include any data except the csrf token. Try adding `id` and `quantity` data. This is just an assumption of the value.

```
       data: {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', id: 6, quantity: 2},
```

Secondly, this function returns a collections of product.

```
$products = Product::all();
```

So if you would like to modify a product you must access its index. e.g.

```
$products[0]->unit_stock = 3; 
$products[0]->save();
```

Or what Lewis has stated, you can use a foreach loop to iterate every object in the collection

Comment: Honestly, I think there are flaws in @Jeff 's code logic. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're trying to update products' stock that has been purchased/ added to cart. Therefore you need to save the ids of each product added in that cart, that you haven't done. Once you've the id of each product, you can use that call `find` function and update the product's quantity.